# Memory Alignment issue with std::map on Linux

Tags: c++, memory, alignment

I have run into a problem while working with c++ over Linux.

I have a base Message class which looks like this:

```
class MsgBase
{
    public:
        MsgBase( unsigned int msgid );
        map < unsigned int, MSGIEBase* > messageIE_Map; // map for IEs
        unsigned int messageId; // 32 bit message id
};
```

class Der1 is derived from MsgBase and looks like:

```
class Der1 : public MsgBase
{
    public:
        Der1 ();
        virtual ~Der1 ();

        // IEs
        MSGIE_UINT32 ueId;
        MSGIE_String configFileName;
};
```

Here MSGIE_UINT32 and MSGIE_String are classes derived from MSGIEBase and therefore their address can be stored in the map defined in base class above.
When Der1 is constructed the address of ueId and configFileName is stored in the map.
Here if I print the size of map ( through gdb and in the program ) it comes to be 24.
[ _M_header = 16, _M_node_count = 4,  _M_key_compare = 1, 3 byte padding I suppose ].

Till here everything is fine. Now the Der1 object pointer is put inside an event object and the event is post into a queue. The event class looks like:

```
class Event 
{
   public:
       MsgBase* msgPtr;
};
```

A different thread removes the event from the queue, extracts the msgPtr and casts it into Der1 Pointer and this is where the problem starts.

Here if I print the size of the map in the program it is 21. That means the address of the next member in the MsgBase class i.e. messageId gets shifted by 3 bytes and so the value of messageId changes completely. (when seen through gdb, the address is still intact and so is the size of the map i.e. 24 ).

This is a word alignment issue to the best of my knowledge but why is the memory alignment not consistent in different functions and why does the address of a member of a class chage when the memory to the class has been allocated using new. I am using Linux 2.6.27. , gcc version 4.1.1. , RHEL-4.

Comment: Depends on how you manipulate those objects. Show your code. (I don't think it's a memory alignment issue)

Comment: I think your assumptions about the size of the map and memory alignment are taking you down the wrong path.  You never explain the actual problem, just symptoms that I don't think are relevant.  What happens (incorrectly) in your program when you pop from your queue?  I would think the push and pop parts of the source at this point would be much more relevant, I'm guessing there is a problem there.

Comment: Is there an actual problem? Show us some of the relevant code.

Comment: Are you using the same identical compiler options for both files?

Comment: `sizeof(std::map<anything,anythingelse>)` could be equal 21 only if you use some weird compiler options and/or pragmas that should not be used normally. Posting your compiler flags here would help.

Answer (score 1):

For ruling out non-virtual destructor/copy/assignment problems, please add the following to `MsgBase`:

```
public:
    virtual ~MsgBase();
private:
    MsgBase(MsgBase const& other);
    MsgBase& operator=(MsgBase const& other);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide all the required information step by step:

Information 1 : The relevant code.

```
//Step 1:  Create msg and fill message Id
MsgBase*msgPtr = new Der1();

// C'tor of Der1 is as follows:
Der1::Der1 ()
          : MsgBase ( ATS_SUTD_EPCTESTER_ATTACH_SCENARIO_MsgId ), // msgid is 13( 0xd )
            ueId ( IE_UE_KEY, "UE", false ),
            configFileName ( IE_CONFIG_FILE_NAME_KEY, "Configuration File Name", false )
{
            // Insert the IEs in the map
this->addIEEntry ( IE_UE_KEY, &ueId ); // this puts entries in the map
this->addIEEntry ( IE_CONFIG_FILE_NAME_KEY, &configFileName );
}

// Step 2: Declare event and post the event
Event* event = new Event ( eventId, "Event" );
event->setData( msgPtr, hdr);

// check the message id at this stage ( 
cout << "msgId  = " << ( ( (Der1* )msgPtr )->messageId )<< endl; // Here it comes out 
                                                          // to be 0xd which is correct

// post the event
AppClass::getInstance()->addEventAndSchedule ( event );

//The queue is a member of AppClass and  has been defined as 
std::list <EventBase* > eventQueue;

// The code which inserts data into the queue is as follows:
bool AppClass::addEventAndSchedule ( EventBase* ev )
{
   if ( ev == NULL ) return false;
   this->eventQueueMutex.acquireLock();
   this->eventQueue.push_back( ev );
   this->eventQueueMutex.releaseLock();

   // Submit Job to Scheduler
   bool status = JobScheduler::getInstance()->scheduleJob( this );
   return status;
}

// The event class is
class Event: public EventBase
{
  public:
  Event ();
  virtual ~Event ();
  Event ( int evId );
  Event ( int evId, string evName );
  MsgBase* getMessagePtr ();
  void setData ( MsgBase*  mPtr, Header* hPtr )

  private:
   // Prevent copying
   Event& operator= ( Event& ev );
   Event ( Event& evBase );

   MsgBase* msgPtr;
   Header*    hdrPtr;
};

void Event::setData ( MsgBase* mPtr,  Header* hPtr )
{
   this->msgPtr = mPtr;
   this->hdrPtr =  hPtr;
}


Step 3 : Extract the event and re-print the message Id
// The code which extracts data from the queue is as follows:
void AppClass::process ()
{
               EventBase* beventPtr = NULL;
               this->eventQueueMutex.acquireLock();

    if ( !this->eventQueue.empty() )
    {
       beventPtr  = (EventBase* )( this->eventQueue.front() );
       this->eventQueue.pop_front();
    }
    else
    {
        isQueueEmpty = true;
    }

    this->eventQueueMutex.releaseLock();
    Event* eventPtr = ( Event* )beventPtr ;

                             Der1* msgPtr = (Der1* )( eventPtr->getMessagePtr()) ;
     cout << "msgId  = " <<  msgPtr->messageId << endl;  // This value
             //comes out to be incorrect it is now 0xd000000  i.e. a 3 byte shift

}
```

Information 2 : Exact problem.
  The exact problem is that the 'messasgeId' is getting changed in transition. Initially it is 0xd but after popping from the queue it becomes 0xd000000. Because of this all the processing stops. The address of this parameter also changes from 0x82bd7cc to 0x82bd7c9 when printed in the program. However when seen from gdb it is still 0x82bd7cc and the value is still 0xd.

Information 3 : Compiler Flags. 
   Compiler Flags are same for all the files and they are:
    -O0 -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0